# How to implement "Open on phone" animation on Android Wear

Tags: wear-os

According to the guidelines: 
https://developer.android.com/design/wear/patterns.html#Continuing

"In cases where the phone must be used, a generic animation should be played once the action button has been tapped and the corresponding Android app will open on the phone."

The animation can be seen in the Google Keep app. Here is a sample recording: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25670071/IMG_0274.MOV

Is there a standard implementation of this animation somewhere?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The steps needed to implement this functionality depends on whether the notification is submitted from phone or from wearable device.

### Notification from phone:

If your notification came from phone - the "Open on phone" action page is added automatically when your notification has [setContentIntent(PendingIntent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) set.

### From your wearable app:

If you need to play this animation in a notification that is submitted from wearable device directly (or from any other place from your wearable application) you will need to launch this animation by yourself.

There is a nice `ConfirmationActivity` that supports few predefined animation types:

- `ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION`
- `ConfirmationActivity.OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION`
- `ConfirmationActivity.FAILURE_ANIMATION`

The animation you should be interested it is `ConfirmationActivity.OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION`. You need to pass the type of animation in the `ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE` extra.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfirmationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE, ConfirmationActivity.OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
```

**IMPORTANT:**
To launch the `ConfirmationActivity` you need to add it to your Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="android.support.wearable.activity.ConfirmationActivity" />
```

### Theme:

Next step is to tweak the style of this `ConfirmationActivity`. For example if you want to **disable the default sliding animation** or to make the window **transparent** you will need to set a custom theme to it in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="android.support.wearable.activity.ConfirmationActivity"
    android:theme="@style/TransparentTheme"/>
```

and define the `TransparentTheme` in `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="TransparentTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It would also be great to know where in the SDK to get the stock "Open on phone" drawable.

Comment: @Warlax Animation is located as drawable: `R.drawable.go_to_phone_animation`. You can use it to build your custom interface, but only if you have good reason not to use standard `ConfirmationActivity` :)

Comment: Oh I wasn't clear about my question. I meant a drawable that I can use to pass into the Action so it looks like the stock "open on phone" action.

Comment: Go to the `R.drawable.go_to_phone_animation` animation drawable and check drawables for separate frames. First frame is stored in `R.drawable.go_to_phone_00156`, probably you can use that as an image for action.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to disable the slide in from the left
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item> should resolve it but for some reason does not work for me. I also tried windowEnterAnimation and set to null but does not work :(. Everything else works like transparent background. Not sure what I am doing wrong....

Comment: I can't edit the above but solved it. For some reason defining it in xml does not work, but I used the ActivityOptions to do it. Code I used is: **context.startActivity(intentAnimation, ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context,0,0).toBundle());**

Comment: An easier way to disable the default sliding animation for the ConfirmationActivity is to add the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION flag on the intent that starts it.

Comment: Another way to disable the sliding animation is after you call `startActivity(intent)` you do this: `overridePendingTransition(0,0);` This overrides the transition and gives it no animation.